# MacOS Xamarin - Google OAuth Callback working in debug and not in release

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api, xamarin.mac

I'm facing an ERROR in the callback in the OAuth process in a MacOS App written in c# / Xamarin.

I'm using Clancey.SimpleAuth for simplify the process (https://github.com/Clancey/SimpleAuth)

Basically in my code I have a simple Auth like:

```
var scopes = new[]
{
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
};
var api = new GoogleApi("google",
   "clientid",
   "clientsecret")
{
    Scopes = scopes,
};

var account = await api.Authenticate();
```

The problem is quite simple:
When I'm in debug everything works fine, the library took the callback, uses the secret to challenge etc.

When I'm in Release, I get this error:

```
2018-02-06 22:48:38.278 MyAppName[2789:37686] -[SimpleAuth_Native_CallBackHelper UrlHandleEvent:event:replyEvent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000c340a0
2018-02-06 22:48:38.279 MyAppName[2789:37686] -[SimpleAuth_Native_CallBackHelper UrlHandleEvent:event:replyEvent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000c340a0
2018-02-06 22:48:38.279 MyAppName[2789:37686] -[SimpleAuth_Native_CallBackHelper UrlHandleEvent:event:replyEvent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000c340a0
2018-02-06 22:48:38.279 MyAppName[2789:37686] -[SimpleAuth_Native_CallBackHelper UrlHandleEvent:event:replyEvent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000c340a0
```

[image]

[image]

What could be the problem / difference between DEBUG & Release Config?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that a static class?

Comment: In your release configuration, turn off the linking behavior (`Don't Link`) and retest.

Comment: @hichame.yessou it uses a Static class SimpleAuth.NativeSafariAuthenticator.Activate();
SushiHangover it's already "don't link"

Comment: Not sure if that's the case but if there is no reference to a static class, the jit compiler will not load the class due to optimization reasons, I would try to remove static, turn off linking behaviour as @SushiHangover said and uncheck Optimize Code of the Build panel of your project

Comment: Tried with no code optimization, still not working. Do you know any other lib I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to fix it with the old "component"

I switched back to the "Official Google" package:

```
            var credential = await Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "IDIDIDIDIDIDgesmfcm.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                ClientSecret = "csL-.........."
            },
                      new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" },
            "user",
                CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("AppStore"));

            Utils.Log("Logged as " + credential.UserId);
            //TOKEN USE
```